# Determining the highest word alphabetically without arrays in java

Tags: java

I have been trying to write a program that does 2 things, finds the longest word in a user generated string and finding the highest word in alphabetical order. I have the longest word working fine, but I cant figure out the alphabetical problem to save my life. the problem I'm running into is how it is comparing the words running in the for loops.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
/*
CSC 190
Hw7
Ryan Burchfield
10/19/17
Purpose: Take a string and return both the Longest and largest words in the String.
 */
package hw7;
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyString{
    String s;

    MyString( String s1 ){
        s=s1;

    }
    void setString(String s1){
        s=s1;

    }
    String getLongest(String s1){
        s1 = s1 +" ";
        int length = s1.length();
        String temp="", longestw="";
        char ltr;
        int templ, longest=0;

        for(int i=0; i<length;i++){

            ltr = s1.charAt(i);
            if(ltr!=' ' && ltr!=',' && ltr!='.'){
                temp=temp+ltr;
            }
            else{
                templ=temp.length();

                if(templ>longest){
                    longest=templ;
                    longestw=temp;
                }
                temp="";
            }
        }
        return longestw;
    }
    String getLargest(String s1){
        s1= s1 + " ";
        String temp="", curWord="",largestW="";
        char ltr;
        for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++){
            ltr = s1.charAt(i);
            if(ltr!=' ' && ltr!=',' && ltr!='.'){
                temp= temp + ltr; 

            }else{


                char ltr1;    
                for(int j=0; j<s1.length(); j++){
                    ltr1 = s1.charAt(j);
                    if(ltr1!=' ' && ltr1!=',' && ltr1!='.'){
                        curWord= curWord + ltr1; 
                    }
                    else{   

                        int largest = temp.compareToIgnoreCase(curWord);
                        System.out.println(temp+","+curWord+","+temp.compareToIgnoreCase(curWord));
                        System.out.println(largest);
                        if(largest > 0){

                            largestW=curWord;
                        }else{
                            largestW=temp;
                        }
                        curWord="";    
                        temp="";  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return largestW;
    }

}


public class Hw7 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a series of words: ");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        MyString s1 = new MyString(s);
        System.out.println("The longest word is: " + s1.getLongest(s));
        System.out.println("The largest word is: " + s1.getLargest(s));
    }

}
```

Comment: First, what do you mean by "highest" in alphabetical order? Given "apple" and "zebra", is "apple" highest - or is "zebra"? Ignoring that, assume the first word is "highest" - compare "highest" to each subsequent word, ***iff*** the current word is "higher" than the current "highest" update "highest" - continue until there are no more words. Return the current highest, which must be **the** highest since we have compared it with every word.

Comment: given apple and zebra, zebra would be the output.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(largest > 0){
>     largestW=curWord;
> }else{
>     largestW=temp;
> }
> ```

This is where the program goes wrong. You did not compare `currWord` / `temp` with `largestW`

A better way to write `getLargest()` is to use the same way as `getLongest()`, i.e. using one loop, and compare `largestW` with `temp` every time (if `largestW` is empty then just set `largestW = temp`)

Answer (score 0):

As your post you can get the longest word. I will show you how to get the highest letter in alphabetical order of the longest word.

- There is a method call toCharArray() you can use this method to make letter array of given word.
- Than you can use casting to get integer value of the given char value
- Then you can compare that integer value to get the highest integer value
- Once you have the highest integer value cast that int value to char to take the letter

Following links to more information

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

http://javaseeeedu.blogspot.com/2015/12/casting-part-1.html

I have change your code try it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyString{
    String s;

    MyString( String s1 ){
        s=s1;

    }
    void setString(String s1){
        s=s1;

    }
    String getLongest(String s1){
        s1 = s1 +" ";
        int length = s1.length();
        String temp="", longestw="";
        char ltr;
        int templ, longest=0;

        for(int i=0; i<length;i++){

            ltr = s1.charAt(i);
            if(ltr!=' ' && ltr!=',' && ltr!='.'){
                temp=temp+ltr;
            }
            else{
                templ=temp.length();

                if(templ>longest){
                    longest=templ;
                    longestw=temp;
                }
                temp="";
            }
        }
        return longestw;
    }
    char getLargest(String s1){

        int max = 0;

        char []arr = s1.toCharArray();

        int temp[] = new int[arr.length];

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){  

            temp[i] = (int)arr[i];
            if(i!=0){

                if(temp[i-1] < temp[i]){
                        max = temp[i];
                }else{

                 max = temp[i-1];   

                }
            }                   
        }   

        return (char)max;
    }

}


class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a series of words: ");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        MyString s1 = new MyString(s);
        System.out.println("The longest word is: " + s1.getLongest(s));
        System.out.println("The largest letter is: " + s1.getLargest(s1.getLongest(s)));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well this is obviously a homework, and you did the homework for the OP instead of telling him what's going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with a single method that takes a `Comparator<String>` and the input `String`; construct a `Scanner` using the [`Scanner(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) constructor and modify the delimiter using [`Scanner#useDelimiter(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) to consume white space, commas, and literal `'.'`. Then use the supplied `Comparator` to compare the tokens available through the `Scanner`. Like,

```
static String findWord(Comparator<String> comp, String s1) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s1);
    sc.useDelimiter("[\\s,\\.]+");
    String max = null;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String token = sc.next();
        if (max == null || comp.compare(max, token) < 0) {
            max = token;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then, assuming you're using Java 8+, `main` can be written using `Comparator`s already available like -

```
Comparator<String> stringLengthComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(
        String::length);
Comparator<String> stringAlphaComparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a series of words: ");
String sentence = in.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Longest: %s%n", findWord(stringLengthComparator, sentence));
System.out.printf("Lexically: %s%n", findWord(stringAlphaComparator, sentence));
```

But, if you're using an earlier version - or you want to better understand what it does, the exact same code will work if you replace the two `Comparator`s with equivalent code - like

```
Comparator<String> stringLengthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());
    }
};
Comparator<String> stringAlphaComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code there, nearly all of which is unnecessary.

Try this:

```
String longest = Arrays.stream(s.split(" +")).sort(comparing(String::length).reversed()).findFirst().get();
String highest = Arrays.stream(s.split(" +")).sort().reduce((a,b) -> b).get();
```

Note: Read and understand the code well before you submit your assignment.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or even work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: OP didn't want to use arrays :)